# Firefox extension: native code execution?

Tags: firefox-addon, native

Is it possible to write an extension that runs native, platform-dependent code? I'm an extension-newbie (what a phrase!) :), can you please point me towards good material on this subject? (good keywords to feed to Google are enough)

([I would like to put a GtkMenu in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172851/creating-native-gtkmenu-from-firefox-extension))

Edit: 
I started checking out the Gecko SDK, and it's a rather big subject, and I'm not sure this is what I want.

I'd be happy with a friendly manual (which is not a raw reference, but rather some kind of tutorial on how to make extensions that utilize XPCOM (if that is the way). Good keywords are still appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [Gecko SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_SDK).

You can use it make portable C++ native code firefox extensions which I believe are XPCOM objects with JavaScript wrappers in the .xpm zip file.

I haven't tried it, but you can go the usual route and write the plugin, I mean extension, in javascript also.

Answer (score 2):

[Native Client](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/) doesn't quite offer the breadths of API firefox extensions offer, but it's still well worth checking out for your purposes IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Witness the [Cooliris extension](http://www.cooliris.com/), that makes (heavy) use of your 3D graphics card, and is Windows specific.